# How to create explode animation for linear recyclerView

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

I am trying to make an explode animation for my linear layout Recycle view. So that when I press the screen, all the items nicely fly away. But for some reason as soon as the animation is initiated, it only happens on a very narrow portion of the screen and everything else is sliced off.

Here is the main activity code:

```
package com.stanislav.disturber;
   
import...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<Alarm> alarms;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private final int DND_OFF = 0;
    private final int DND_ON = 1;

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            Window w = getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance
            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        }


        alarms = new ArrayList<>();
        Alarm firstAlarm = new Alarm("This is the on alarm\n\n");
        firstAlarm.setAlarmKind(DND_ON);
        alarms.add(firstAlarm);

        Alarm thAlarm = new Alarm("And this one is the off alarm\n\n");
        secondAlarm.setAlarmKind(DND_OFF);
        alarms.add(thAlarm);
...

        Alarm niAlarm = new Alarm("And this one is the off alarm\n\n");
        secondAlarm.setAlarmKind(DND_OFF);
        alarms.add(niAlarm);


        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
        DisturberAdapter disturberAdapter = new DisturberAdapter(alarms, this);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, true);
        linearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(alarms.size()-1);
        RecyclerView.ItemAnimator itemAnimator = new DefaultItemAnimator();

        recyclerView.setAdapter(disturberAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(itemAnimator);
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // save rect of view in screen coordinates
                final Rect viewRect = new Rect();
                v.getGlobalVisibleRect(viewRect);

                // create Explode transition with epicenter
                Transition explode = new Explode();
                explode.setEpicenterCallback(new Transition.EpicenterCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public Rect onGetEpicenter(Transition transition) {
                        return viewRect;
                    }
                });
                explode.setDuration(7000);
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(recyclerView, explode);

                // remove all views from Recycler View
                recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

[image: animation in progress]
[image: Initial view]

Comment: I'd use https://developer.android.com/studio/write/motion-editor.

Comment: Thanks Martin! This is something I didn't know, I will give it a try for sure!

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that the problem shows up when the height of recyclerview is set to "wrap content". But without "wrap content" how on Earth to have cards in the middle if there are only few of them?

Also when the height is set to "wrap content", what causes problems - padding in recyclerview!! Weird!

A temporary solution is: in the animation routine, add the following line, to give recyclerview enormously ridiculous padding. Then everything will work. Just don't forget to return the previous padding back afterwards!! The code:

```
 recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                
                //Set enormous padding
                recyclerView.setPadding(0,2000,0,2000);
                
                
                // save rect of view in screen coordinates
                final Rect viewRect = new Rect();
                //v.getGlobalVisibleRect(viewRect);

                //create Explode transition with epicenter
                Transition explode = new Explode();
                explode.setEpicenterCallback(new Transition.EpicenterCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public Rect onGetEpicenter(Transition transition) {
                        return viewRect;
                    }
                });

                explode.setDuration(600);
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(recyclerView, explode);


                // remove all views from Recycler View
                recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
                return false;
            }
        });
```